# Помогите адаптировать под планшет и телефон?

Tags: css3

помогите адаптировать под планшет и телефон

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'pt-sans';
 src: url('../fonts/pt-sans.ttf');
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url("../images/sunflowers.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover; 
 min-height:100vh; 
}

.header_g {
 color: #fff;
 width: 1250px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 42px;
}

.header_menu {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.icons {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.icons img {
 margin-right: 21px;
}

.icons div { 
 margin-left: 40px;
 line-height: 22px;
}

.menu a {color: #fff;}

.menu li {margin-right: 103px;}

.menu ul  {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.menu { margin: 0 auto; }

.menu ul img {
 
 margin-top: -21px;
}

button {
 margin-top: -30px;
 width: 160px;
 height: 46px;
 line-height: 30px;
 background: #F5940C;
 border: 1px solid #F5940C;
 color: #fff;
}

@media screen (max-width:1024px) {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/reset.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="header_g">
   <div class="header_menu">
    <div class="icons">
     <a href=""><img src="images/facebook.png" alt=""></a>
     <a href=""><img src="images/twitt.png" alt=""></a>
     <a href=""><img src="images/Instagram.png" alt=""></a>
     <div>RU <img src="images/vector.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="images/hello.png" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     <a href=""><button>BUY NOW</button></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: reset.css обычно в начале должен подключатся, проще все делать в инспекторе, главный плюс все это в реальном времени, меняйте значения и сразу же заносите в медиа условие, смотрите где находятся фиксированные размеры и меняйте их значения на ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 1):

А дальше уже сам думаешь что изменить чтобы на дейвасе смотрелось и смотришь через веб инспектор.(В хроме ctrl+shift+i)
Я сам нуб, но вроде лучше начинать стили с мобильного вида и через @media уже добавлять остальные.